# PHP modules missing from command line version when using apt-get

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm installing my PHP environment in a docker container using Ubuntu 18.04 as the OS, with various add-on modules, using this command:

```
RUN apt-get install -y php8.0 php8.0-curl php8.0-gd php8.0-gettext php8.0-gmp php8.0-iconv php8.0-imap php8.0-intl php8.0-mbstring php8.0-mysql php8.0-oauth php8.0-redis php8.0-xdebug php8.0-xml php8.0-yaml php8.0-zip
RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php
```

All the modules seem to work fine when running PHP from the Apache environment. However, when I run PHP from the command line, it becomes apparent that some of them are missing. For example, I get errors like:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /var/www/btk/index.php:42
```

From running `php -i`, I can see that the `mbstring` module isn't loaded, and that the configuration files are different: `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` for the command line version, `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini` for the Apache version.

Obviously, I could hand-hack `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` after installation (presumably in the `Dockerfile`), but I would far prefer to stop the problem from happening in the first place.

Is there a "clean" way of telling the `apt-get` package installer to enable the additional modules in the command line as well as in Apache?

Comment: It looks like you're running 8.1 instead of 8.0 on the command line, so you can either change PHP versions, or install the libraries for 8.1

Comment: Sharp eyes! I hadn't spotted that. Interesting question as to how 8.1 got installed when I didn't mention it anywhere in my install script - but that gives me a lead as to what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aynber, who pointed me in the right direction.

The following command in the Dockerfile sorts things out:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0
```

I really don't understand why this happened, when I didn't ask for php 8.1 to exist at any stage, but this solves the problem. I can also see whether I want to just upgrade the whole lot to 8.1.